# Inconsistent results between Powershell and C# .NET AD group memberships

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory, ldap

The following Powershell command gives me a result of 44:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -server domain.local "domain admins" | measure
```

The following Powershell command gives me a result of 34:

```
Get-ADGroup -properties * 'domain admins' | select -expandproperty member | measure
```

The following C# code gives me a result of 34:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GT()
{
    string groupname = "CN=Domain Admins,CN=Users";
    string domain = "DC=domain,DC=local";
    DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + groupname + "," + domain);
    var count = 0;
    foreach (object dn in de.Properties["member"])
    {
        count++;
        Regex r = new Regex("CN=(.*?)(?:,[A-Z]+=|$)");
    }
    Console.WriteLine(count);
}
```

What could be the reason for this inconsistency? It looks like the "member" property is what is really at issue here - does it not look at service accounts maybe?

**EDIT** It appears that if the primary group ID is set to 512 (domain admin), it will not be reflected as a member due to legacy issues.  My question is if there is any way to, in .NET, get all of these in one query.  (I want to use GroupPrincipal, but it is giving me referral errors for the Enterprise Admins group)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue, as noted in the edit, was that if old user accounts from legacy days were present, with a primary group ID of 512, they would not appear in the Domain Admins group.

Therefore, I had to use the following filter:

(|(primaryGroupId=512)(memberOf=CN=Domain Admins,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local))

This gave me the full listing!